# adding a UIView on a UIScrollVIew during the zoom mode

Tags: iphone, ipad, uiscrollview, zooming

i'm trying to place a UIView on a scrollView during its zoomed state. I want the UIView to be seen on the scrollView and also to resize along with it once the scrollView is zoomed out.. i am able to place the UIView on scrollView during the zoomed state. But the UIView is not getting resized after zooming out... Should i apply any transforms here??? can anyone help me in this please... Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can use a little trick: before zoom is started get the screenshot of the view (with subviews) that you want to zoom. Add that image to the UIImageView add return it via `viewForZoomingInScrollView:`. So you actually zoom the image of that view and not the one itself.
After zoom ended scale your actual view manually.

You can find out how to get screen shot from my post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5002789/iphone-get-uiimage-from-views-layers/5002882#5002882)