# iOS: Getting real-time (ish) video data

Tags: ios, video, camera

I'm trying to write an program that, as part of its functionality, continuously captures video and calculates the average luminance of the video data of the given frame in real-time, or as close to real-time as possible. This is my first foray into any video stuff/iOS camera things at all, so I've kind of just schlepped a lot of things I've researched on the internet together in addition to my own stuff. Right now this code in my ViewController.m file will compile and run on my device, but it doesn't appear to be doing anything:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    _val = 0;

    //Set up the video capture session.
    NSLog(@"Setting up the capture session...\n");
    captureSession = [[AVCaptureSession alloc] init];

    //Add input.
    NSLog(@"Adding video input...\n");
    AVCaptureDevice *captureDevice = [self frontFacingCameraIfAvailable];
    if(captureDevice){
        NSError *error;
        videoInputDevice = [AVCaptureDeviceInput deviceInputWithDevice:captureDevice error:&error];
        if(!error){
            if([captureSession canAddInput:videoInputDevice])
                [captureSession addInput:videoInputDevice];
            else
                NSLog(@"Couldn't add video input.\n");

        }else{
            NSLog(@"Couldn't create video input.\n");
        }
    }else{
        NSLog(@"Couldn't create capture device.\n");
    }

    //Add output.
    NSLog(@"Adding video data output...\n");
    vidOutput = [[AVCaptureVideoDataOutput alloc] init];
    vidOutput.alwaysDiscardsLateVideoFrames = YES;
    if([captureSession canAddOutput:vidOutput])
        [captureSession addOutput:vidOutput];
    else
        NSLog(@"Couldn't add video output.\n");
    NSString* key = (NSString*)kCVPixelBufferPixelFormatTypeKey;
    NSNumber* value = [NSNumber numberWithUnsignedInt:kCVPixelFormatType_420YpCbCr8BiPlanarFullRange];
    NSDictionary* videoSettings = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:value forKey:key];
    [vidOutput setVideoSettings:videoSettings];
    dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_queue_create("MyQueue", NULL);
    [vidOutput setSampleBufferDelegate:self queue:queue];

}

- (void)viewDidUnload{
    [super viewDidUnload];
    // Release any retained subviews of the main view.
}

-(AVCaptureDevice *)frontFacingCameraIfAvailable{
    NSArray *videoDevices = [AVCaptureDevice devicesWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo];
    AVCaptureDevice *captureDevice = nil;
    for (AVCaptureDevice *device in videoDevices){
        if (device.position == AVCaptureDevicePositionFront){
            captureDevice = device;
            break;
        }
    }

    //couldn't find one on the front, so just get the default video device.
    if (!captureDevice){
        captureDevice = [AVCaptureDevice defaultDeviceWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo];
    }

    return captureDevice;
}

- (void)captureOutput:(AVCaptureOutput *)captureOutput didOutputSampleBuffer:(CMSampleBufferRef)sampleBuffer fromConnection: (AVCaptureConnection *)connection{
    // Create autorelease pool because we are not in the main_queue
    @autoreleasepool {
        CVImageBufferRef imageBuffer = CMSampleBufferGetImageBuffer(sampleBuffer);
        // Lock the imagebuffer
        CVPixelBufferLockBaseAddress(imageBuffer,0);
        // Get information about the image
        uint8_t *baseAddress = (uint8_t *)CVPixelBufferGetBaseAddress(imageBuffer);
        // size_t bytesPerRow = CVPixelBufferGetBytesPerRow(imageBuffer);
        size_t width = CVPixelBufferGetWidth(imageBuffer);
        size_t height = CVPixelBufferGetHeight(imageBuffer);
        size_t bytesPerRow = CVPixelBufferGetBytesPerRow(imageBuffer);
        CVPlanarPixelBufferInfo_YCbCrBiPlanar *bufferInfo = (CVPlanarPixelBufferInfo_YCbCrBiPlanar *)baseAddress;
        // This just moved the pointer past the offset
        baseAddress = (uint8_t *)CVPixelBufferGetBaseAddressOfPlane(imageBuffer, 0);
        // convert the image
        UIImage *image = [self makeImage:baseAddress bufferInfo:bufferInfo width:width height:height bytesPerRow:bytesPerRow];
        // Update the display with the captured image for DEBUG purposes
        //dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            //[self.vImage setImage:image];
        //});
        CGImageRef cgImage = [image CGImage];
        CGDataProviderRef provider = CGImageGetDataProvider(cgImage);
        CFDataRef bitmapData = CGDataProviderCopyData(provider);
        const UInt8* data = CFDataGetBytePtr(bitmapData);
        int cols = width - 1;
        int rows = height - 1;
        float avgLuminance = 0.0;
        for(int i = 0; i < cols; i++){
            for(int j = 0; j < rows; j++){
                const UInt8* pixel = data + j*bytesPerRow + i*4;
                avgLuminance += pixel[0]*0.299 + pixel[1]*0.587 + pixel[2]*0.114;
            }
        }
        avgLuminance /= (cols*rows);
        NSLog(@"Average Luminance: %f\n", avgLuminance);

    }
}

-(UIImage *)makeImage:(uint8_t *)inBaseAddress bufferInfo:(CVPlanarPixelBufferInfo_YCbCrBiPlanar *)inBufferInfo width: (size_t)Width height:(size_t)Height bytesPerRow:(size_t)BytesPerRow{
    NSUInteger yPitch = EndianU32_BtoN(inBufferInfo->componentInfoY.rowBytes);
    uint8_t *rgbBuffer = (uint8_t *)malloc(Width * Height * 4);
    uint8_t *yBuffer = (uint8_t *)inBaseAddress;
    uint8_t val;
    int bytesPerPixel = 4;
    // for each byte in the input buffer, fill in the output buffer with four bytes
    // the first byte is the Alpha channel, then the next three contain the same
    // value of the input buffer
    for(int y = 0; y < Height*Width; y++){
        val = yBuffer[y];
        // Alpha channel
        rgbBuffer[(y*bytesPerPixel)] = 0xff;
        // next three bytes same as input
        rgbBuffer[(y*bytesPerPixel)+1] = rgbBuffer[(y*bytesPerPixel)+2] = rgbBuffer[y*bytesPerPixel+3] = val;
    }

    // Create a device-dependent RGB color space
    CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
    CGContextRef context = CGBitmapContextCreate(rgbBuffer, yPitch, Height, 8,yPitch*bytesPerPixel, colorSpace, kCGBitmapByteOrder32Little | kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedLast);
    CGImageRef quartzImage = CGBitmapContextCreateImage(context);
    CGContextRelease(context);
    //UIImage *image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithCGImage:quartzImage scale:(CGFloat)0.5 orientation:UIImageOrientationRight];
    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:quartzImage];
    CGImageRelease(quartzImage);
    free(rgbBuffer);
    return image;
}
```

I set my .h file as an `AVCaptureVideoDataOutputSampleBufferDelegate` but I get the feeling that I'm not quite understanding what I need to do in my code to be constantly getting data from the camera, as the CaptureOutput method never gets called anywhere. How/where should I be calling it in order to get a constant stream of data?

Comment: Well what I would do is create a snapshot of a AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer (reference http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5002789/get-uiimage-from-views-layers) then take the data from that. This might not be as clean as you want though so take it with a grain of salt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm an idiot. All I needed was this:

```
[captureSession startRunning];
```

Imagine that. Heh.